# How to execute a script through sqlcmd in MS Sql server

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I got a .sql file in which {0} kind of things used. I would like to know how can i pass values in the sqlcmd for {0} variable.

Sample script (test.sql):

```
GO
PRINT '{0}'
GO
```

And I am trying to executing through this command line

```
sqlcmd -S . -d master -E -i test.sql
```

But, where should i pass the parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Just Try as below:

test.sql

GO
Print $var
GO

sqlcmd -S . -d master -E -i test.sql -v var="helloWorld"

Comment: then i have to change the sql script. Is there any way to pass unnamed arguments through sqlcmd utility

Comment: Try your luck for variable name as -v {0}="HelloWorld"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the -v switch to pass in variables:

```
sqlcmd -S . -d master -E -i test.sql -v varPrintMe="{0}"
```

Then you'll need to put the variables in $() in your sql script:

```
GO
PRINT $('varPrintMe')
GO
```

Comment: then i have to change the sql script. Is there any way to pass unnamed arguments through sqlcmd utility

Comment: You will have to change the sql script anyway - you don't have the variables identified properly within the script.  It needs to be $(variablename).